# too many values to unpack (expected 3) pygame click issue

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, click

I am currently working on a CS50 project studying the AI required for tic-tac-toe. however I can't get the runner.py file to run, as I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/newtracksuit/Downloads/tictactoe/runner.py", line 57, in
>
> click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

here is the full code provided, I have yet to write any actual functionality to the tic-tac-toe program, Just need to understand why this is not working yet

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

import tictactoe as ttt

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600, 400

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

mediumFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 28)
largeFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 40)
moveFont = pygame.font.Font("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 60)

user = None
board = ttt.initial_state()
ai_turn = False

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(black)

    # Let user choose a player.
    if user is None:

        # Draw title
        title = largeFont.render("Play Tic-Tac-Toe", True, white)
        titleRect = title.get_rect()
        titleRect.center = ((width / 2), 50)
        screen.blit(title, titleRect)

        # Draw buttons
        playXButton = pygame.Rect((width / 8), (height / 2), width / 4, 50)
        playX = mediumFont.render("Play as X", True, black)
        playXRect = playX.get_rect()
        playXRect.center = playXButton.center
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, playXButton)
        screen.blit(playX, playXRect)

        playOButton = pygame.Rect(5 * (width / 8), (height / 2), width / 4, 50)
        playO = mediumFont.render("Play as O", True, black)
        playORect = playO.get_rect()
        playORect.center = playOButton.center
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, playOButton)
        screen.blit(playO, playORect)

        # Check if button is clicked
        click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click == 1:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if playXButton.collidepoint(mouse):
                time.sleep(0.2)
                user = ttt.X
            elif playOButton.collidepoint(mouse):
                time.sleep(0.2)
                user = ttt.O

    else:

        # Draw game board
        tile_size = 80
        tile_origin = (width / 2 - (1.5 * tile_size),
                       height / 2 - (1.5 * tile_size))
        tiles = []
        for i in range(3):
            row = []
            for j in range(3):
                rect = pygame.Rect(
                    tile_origin[0] + j * tile_size,
                    tile_origin[1] + i * tile_size,
                    tile_size, tile_size
                )
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, rect, 3)

                if board[i][j] != ttt.EMPTY:
                    move = moveFont.render(board[i][j], True, white)
                    moveRect = move.get_rect()
                    moveRect.center = rect.center
                    screen.blit(move, moveRect)
                row.append(rect)
            tiles.append(row)

        game_over = ttt.terminal(board)
        player = ttt.player(board)

        # Show title
        if game_over:
            winner = ttt.winner(board)
            if winner is None:
                title = f"Game Over: Tie."
            else:
                title = f"Game Over: {winner} wins."
        elif user == player:
            title = f"Play as {user}"
        else:
            title = f"Computer thinking..."
        title = largeFont.render(title, True, white)
        titleRect = title.get_rect()
        titleRect.center = ((width / 2), 30)
        screen.blit(title, titleRect)

        # Check for AI move
        if user != player and not game_over:
            if ai_turn:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                move = ttt.minimax(board)
                board = ttt.result(board, move)
                ai_turn = False
            else:
                ai_turn = True

        # Check for a user move
        click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click == 1 and user == player and not game_over:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    if (board[i][j] == ttt.EMPTY and tiles[i][j].collidepoint(mouse)):
                        board = ttt.result(board, (i, j))

        if game_over:
            againButton = pygame.Rect(width / 3, height - 65, width / 3, 50)
            again = mediumFont.render("Play Again", True, black)
            againRect = again.get_rect()
            againRect.center = againButton.center
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, againButton)
            screen.blit(again, againRect)
            click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if click == 1:
                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if againButton.collidepoint(mouse):
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    user = None
                    board = ttt.initial_state()
                    ai_turn = False

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed)

> Returns a sequence of booleans representing the state of all the mouse buttons.

The number of buttons is either 4 or 6, that depends on the version of pygame. I recommend to get the state of a single button by subscription:

```py
buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if button[0] == 1:
    # [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is returned when you execute `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`? I see `(0, 0, 0)` which is the three arguments your code expects.

You could work out what your code is returning and add the requisite number of underscores, but if you aren't interested in the remaining arguments, you can use `*` to handle the rest of the returned values, e.g.

```
click, *_ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
```